# Setting a pointer to an object, having objects point to each other

Tags: c++

I am creating a class called Team. How can I get two objects to point to each other as Partners? Here is what I have been working on thus far. I have tested it with just the boolean data field and I know the rest of my program works so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 class Team
{
    public:

    Team();
    Team(bool prac, Team *part);
    Team *partner;
    bool practiced;
    void createPairing (Team *t1, Team *t2);
};


Team::Team()
{
    practiced = false;
    partner = 0;
}

Team::Team(bool prac, Team *part)
{
    practiced = prac;
    partner = part;
}

void Team::createPairing (Team *t1, Team *t2)
{
    t1->partner = t2;
    t2->partner = t1;
}

int main()
{
    Team Harry;
    Team Ron;
    Team *p1 = &Harry;
    Team *p2 = &Ron;
    Team createPairing(p1, p2);

    cout << Harry.partner << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createPairing` should be `static`:

```
static void createPairing(Team* t1, Team* t2);
```

Other than that, the problem is that when you do `Team createPairing(p1, p2);`, you're not actually calling the `createPairing` function, you're calling the **second constructor** *implicitly*. It's creating a `Team` called `createPairing` and converting `p1` to a `bool`. (There should be a warning for this when you compile assuming you have **warnings on**.)

After you make the `createPairing` function `static`, this is how you would call it:

```
Team::createPairing(&Harry, &Ron);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The following is still returning 0 for the partner, though. When I tried to place static void in the function declaration, my compiler gave me an error saying that static can only be specified in the class definition. That is, I defined static void (createPartner) in the class definition, but I can't do the same for when defining the function.

Comment: @AnnVeal Yes, you just do it on the declaration inside the class.

Comment: Only use `static` inside the class. When you write the implementation of the function, you shouldn't use `static`.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. However, it's still returning 0 for the partner after I use the function and print cout << Harry.partner << endl;

Comment: Could you pastebin (http://pastie.org) the updated code? (So we're on the same page)

Comment: To clarify, the code in the pastebin is the one that still returns 0

Comment: I told you, you should be calling it like this: `Team::createPairing(p1, p2);`. The `::` operator is important. Currently, in your code, you're creating an instance of the class and calling the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what part of the code you were referring to. Thanks for your help! works now!

Comment: One more quick question... what would be the syntax for dereferencing the partner? For example, in this pastebin I want the third cout to be Ron. Right now, it shows the address of Ron. [link]http://pastie.org/7141176

Comment: `*(Harry.partner)` <- That's how you would dereference it. You can't pass it to `cout` and expect it to display `Ron` however. You need to add an `std::string` member to the `Team` class and set the names correctly there. Then you would add a `getName()` method or if you want, a `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two parameters for pairing you should make that a free function (outside the class). Otherwise I suggest to omit the first parameter (it's "this" from the objects' point of view). Both will help to prevent the error for which magtheridon96 already provided the fix.

```
void Team::createPairing (Team *other)
{
    partner = other;
    other->partner = this; // here, making the member private and providing a setter would be better
}
```

or, as a free function (with setter)

```
void createPairing(Team& lhs, Team& rhs) // use references to avoid potential pointer issues
{
    lhs.setPartner(&rhs);
    rhs.setPartner(&lhs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Team
{ 
    public:

    Team();
    Team(bool prac, Team *part);
    Team *partner;
    bool practiced;
    static void createPairing (Team *t1, Team *t2);
};


Team::Team()
{
    practiced = false;
    partner = 0;
}

Team::Team(bool prac, Team *part)
{
    practiced = prac;
    partner = part;
}

void Team::createPairing (Team *t1, Team *t2)
{
    t1->partner = t2;
    t2->partner = t1;
}

int main()
 {
    Team Harry;
    Team Ron;
    Team *p1 = &Harry;
    Team *p2 = &Ron;
    Team::createPairing(p1, p2);


    return 0;
}
```